# Copy data from one column to other column (which is in a different table and different database)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy one table column value to another table. But both are in different databases. I did this but

```
UPDATE dbo.Excelimp.Furniture
SET dbo.Excelimp.Furniture.AssetId = dbo.Sample.FADetailsNew.AssetNo
FROM dbo.Excelimp.Furniture 
JOIN Sample
ON dbo.Excelimp.Furniture.AssetName=dbo.Sample.FADetailsNew.AssetName
```

but it seems the error

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Excelimp.Furniture'.

Comment: can you please be more specific and tell which is the current database and another database from which you are copying the column.

Comment: my current db is Sample and the target table is in Excelimp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Need of writing schema with column name you can write as below also

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.AssetId = T2.AssetNo
FROM Excelimp.Furniture T1
JOIN Sample.FADetailsNew T2
ON T1.AssetName=T2.AssetName
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.Excelimp.Furniture'. again :(

Comment: Thanks it works I changed line Excelimp.Furniture T1 & Sample.FADetailsNew T2 to      Excelimp.dbo.Furniture T1  & Sample.dbo.FADetailsNew T2 :)

Comment: is it possible to copy values after truncate the target table?

Comment: If you truncate the table then join will be not possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE Furniture
SET Furniture.AssetId = T2.AssetNo
FROM Sample.dbo.FADetailsNew AS T2
WHERE Furniture.AssetName = T2.AssetName
```

Comment: it seems the error   "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.Sample.FADetailsNew'."

Comment: Thanks it works I changed line Sample.FADetailsNew AS T2 to Sample.dbo.FADetailsNew AS T2

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,Invalid error objects is coming because SQL server did not had that Object.Below query shows all the objects present in the Database.

```
SELECT name AS object_name   
  ,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name  
  ,type_desc  
  ,create_date  
  ,modify_date  
FROM sys.objects    
GO
```

.
 **Specify your database name,Schema Name, table name and column name.**

*Try removing "dbo." from your code and run it.*